# Displaying posts on Homepage

Tags: posts, loop, get-posts

I am wondering how to add a column to my homepage that shows the five most recent posts from the blog page located under the "Latest News" heading.

Here is the link to my development site.

http://pur-vent.29kdev.com/

and below is the code that I believe I must edit to achieve this.

If anyone could offer any advice I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks in advance.

- Mike

`“”`

```
<?php if ( get_option('modest_featured') == 'on' ) get_template_part('includes/featured'); ?>

<?php if ( get_option('modest_blog_style') == 'false' ){ ?>
    <div id="blurbs" class="clearfix">
        <?php 
            $blurbs_number = get_option('modest_use_third_page') == 'on' ? 3 : 2;
            if ( get_option('modest_use_third_page') == 'on' ) $blurbs_number = 3; 
        ?>
        <?php for ($i=1; $i <= $blurbs_number; $i++) { ?>
            <?php query_posts('page_id=' . get_pageId(html_entity_decode(get_option('modest_home_page_'.$i)))); while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php 
                    global $more; $more = 0;
                ?>
                <div class="blurb<?php if ( $i == 3 ) echo ' last'; ?>">
                    <h3 class="title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>                        
                    <?php the_excerpt(''); ?>



                </div> <!-- end .blurb -->
            <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php if ( $blurbs_number == 2 ) { ?>
            <div class="blurb last">
                <h3 class="title"><?php esc_html_e('Examples of Our Work','Modest'); ?></h3>
                <?php query_posts("showposts=".get_option('modest_work_number')."&cat=".get_cat_ID(get_option('modest_work_cat')));
                    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <?php 
                        $width = 56;
                        $height = 56;
                        $titletext = get_the_title();

                        $thumbnail = get_thumbnail($width,$height,'item-image',$titletext,$titletext,true,'Work');
                        $thumb = $thumbnail["thumb"];
                        $fancybox_title = get_post_meta($post->ID,'Customtitle',true) ? get_post_meta($post->ID,'Customtitle',true) : get_the_title(); ?>
                        <div class="thumb">
                            <a rel="gallery" title="<?php echo esc_attr($fancybox_title); ?>" href="<?php echo esc_attr($thumbnail['fullpath']); ?>" class="fancybox">
                                <?php print_thumbnail($thumb, $thumbnail["use_timthumb"], $titletext, $width, $height, 'item-image'); ?>
                                <span class="overlay"></span>
                                <span class="zoom-icon"></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>  <!-- end .thumb -->
                    <?php 
                    endwhile; endif; 
                wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </div> <!-- end .blurb -->
        <?php } ?>
    </div> <!-- end #blurbs -->
<?php } else { ?>
    <div id="left-area">
        <?php get_template_part('includes/entry','home'); ?>
    </div>  <!-- end #left-area -->
    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following using WP_Query:

```
<div class="news-column">
    <h3>Latest News</h3>
    <ul>
        <?php
        //get news
        $args->posts_per_page = 5;

        //query
        $query = new WP_Query($args);
        while($query->have_posts()):$query->the_post();
            ?>
            <li class="news-item">
                <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
                <p><?php the_date('F jS, Y'); ?></p>
                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                <p class="footnotes"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Continue reading</a></p>
            </li>
            <?php
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can read more about other params to use here: codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query